# Error 6013 when adding view (PostgreSql)

Tags: .net, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, npgsql

warning 6013: The table/view 'view_name' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.

Comment: What's your question? What is your view DDL ?